# CTRL-^ work in Vim but not in Neovim

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, buffers, multiple-files

I'm reading Neovim's `usr_07.txt`.

When I start Neovim like `neovim t1.txt t2.txt t3.txt`, and then issue `:next`, the shortcut `CTRL+^` is supposed to bring me to the previous file (i.e., the alternate file).

This shortcut works in Vim but does nothing in NeoVim.

Instead `CTRL-6` works both on Vim and NeoVim.

Why is that?

May it depend on the fact that my keyboard does not have a US-layout?

I have an Italian keyboard with QWERTY layout.

Comment: You mentioned your keyboard doesn’t have US layout, which is useful, but it would have been helpful to say *which* layout your keyboard has! Can you please [edit] the question to indicate which layout you have?

Comment: @filbranden done